# Using git with cgit for decentralized/centralized development

Tags: git

I plan to use git for hosting my projects on my server.

I've read about [cgit](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/), [git-daemon](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html), and I more or less decided to use those tools. But general use is still kind of confusing for me.

What do I need to set up on the server, to push my files onto it. And when the files on the server are newer as the files on my computer, how do I merge them?

Also, I use, say, two computers where I develop. How do I merge from one computer to the other?

Also, when two people are working on the same project, how do they merge their local repos from one another?

As you probably can tell by now, I come from SVN, but I've worked with Mercurial and now I'd like to test git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to set up on the server, to push my files onto it.

Just install git on the server. And `mkdir repo_name` and `cd repo_name` then do `git init --bare`, then push via ssh.

> And when the files on the server are newer as the files on my computer, how do I merge them?

`git remote add remote_name login@server:/path/to/repo.git`

`git fetch remote_name`

`git merge remote_name/branch_name`

or do a rebase instead.

> Also, when two people are working on the same project, how do they merge their local repos from one another?

First, your colleagues need to clone your repo, or run `git remote add` in their existing repo. `git fetch yourremote` will get all your commits to your colleague's local repo, then he run `git merge yourremote/branch_name`to merge the change. Then he `git push myownremote`

Git is hard to learn, [progit](http://progit.org) and [git community book](http://book.git-scm.com/) are both free and teaches to start using git, setup git server. Github is a great service to use ( the workflow stays the same as you private lan )

Comment: `git pull` to fetch and merge in one step.

Comment: OK, and what if don't have a name for a branch yet? And what about cgit? How do I set that up with a remote repo?

Comment: It think you have to name a branch to push it to a server (bare repo), read here: http://progit.org/book/ch4-2.html